# How to modify query string when debugging JSPs in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, query-string

I just set up Eclipse with Tomcat so that I can debug JSP files. One thing I still haven't figured out is how to modify the URL that Eclipse uses for the JSP page so that I can pass parameters in through the query string. 
Any info provided will be much appreciated.

Comment: What is your method for debugging the JSPs?  I usually just start my server and access the pages from a URL, so clearly you could pass parameters in from your browser window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @SeanA pointed out, you can run the Tomcat server in Eclipse and then access from your browser to the JSP, adding as many parameters as you want. Unfortunately it seems that in **Run > Run configurations** there's no way to configure the query string to run your JSP with... Only arguments for the application server are allowed.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to save the full url in the run/debug configurations like I do with PHP files. I'll use the extneral browser instead.